# How to get data from ruby hash access to laravel 8?

Tags: ruby, laravel, postgresql

I have data stored in a database like this

```
--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
accepted: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  number_of_order: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
    condition: between_number
    value: 0&5
removed: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess {}
```

But I have to display it like this in laravel

```
{"accepted"=>{"last_order_total"=>{"condition"=>"between_number", "value"=>"1000&2000"}, "last_order_date"=>{"condition"=>"before", "value"=>"2021-10-01T00:00:00.000Z"}, "number_of_order"=>{"condition"=>"between_number", "value"=>"10&20"}}, "removed"=>{"last_order_date"=>{"condition"=>"after", "value"=>"2021-10-14T00:00:00.000Z"}, "last_order_total"=>{"condition"=>"between_number", "value"=>"1200&1500"}}}
```

so how can convert database values like this? And I'm using Postgresql to store data.

Comment: That's a very strange way to store data in a database...

Comment: Could you delete all references of `!ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess` from the string, then parse it as regular YAML?

Comment: Hello, @TomLord No I can't delete references because it's already in use in other application.

Comment: I mean delete after fetching it. Step 1: Read data from the database. Step 2: Delete the references. Step 3: Parse the YAML. Step 4: Display it.

Comment: I am not suggesting that you update anything in the database.

Comment: @TomLord Okay I will try now thank you for the suggestion

Comment: These database fields have been written using Rails' ActiveRecord `serialize` method. Although not trivial, you could spin up a very small Rails application to access this table, or ask the application developers to provide you access to the data via an application endpoint. Failing those suggestions, you could export the data and then manually mangle it, but its going to be messy and time-consuming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're unable to reformat data in the database, and that running a  ruby application to fetch this data is not practical, I would suggest stripping any mention of `!ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess` from the value *after reading it*:

1. Fetch the YAML (string) from the database.
2. Strip `!ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess` from the string.
3. Parse the result as regular YAML
4. Display it as you wish.

Comment: The question assumes php, not ruby.