# How to convert laravel array to ruby hash access

Tags: ruby, laravel

I have an array that store some data like this and this is the exact input I'm using

```
{
    "accepted" => {
        "number_of_order" => {
            "condition" => "between_number", "value" => "0&5"
        }
    }, "removed" => {
        
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to convert this array into ruby hash access like this and this is my expected output it's not what I'm getting now

```
--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
accepted: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  number_of_order: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
    condition: between_number
    value: 0&5
removed: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess {}
```

But I'm unable to convert the array in ruby hash access. I also try YAML dump `Yaml::dump($array);` to convert into YAML then ruby hash access but nothing works.

Basically, I'm trying to do reverse of this question

[How to get data from ruby hash access to laravel 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69810393/how-to-get-data-from-ruby-hash-access-to-laravel-8)

You can refer above link I convert this ruby hash into a laravel array but now I also wanted to convert this array into ruby hash.

My current code for converting an array to a ruby hash

```
$jsonEncoded = '{"accepted":{"number_of_order":{"consition":"between_number","value":"0&5"}}}';

$array = json_decode($jsonEncoded, true);

dump(Yaml::dump($array));
```

My current code for converting ruby hash to array

```
$filter_data = str_replace("!ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess", "", $filter_data);
$yamlContents = Yaml::parse($filter_data);
```

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. You write that you have a Lavaral array that you want to convert to Ruby but then you post a nested hash that is already valid Ruby. Then you write about encryption but there is no encrypted value in your example. Can you please elaborate on the exact input data and the expected output and share the code you already have?

Comment: Hello, @spickermann sorry for your unclarity that the shared array is exact input and after that, I share ruby code that is actually my expected output which I want. And I'm editing my question to share my code. You can refer to that link I shared so you can understand it properly. and sorry for using encryption keyword.

Comment: @HitenGal can you tell me the reason why you want activerecord format yaml output, I did not understand the question I was thinking that you are unable to load the yaml and want to convert it to php from ruby or vice versa

Comment: @Chandan I have to store data like this. Because there is a Shopify app which strong data with ActiveSupport method in ruby so I have to manage this data with laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer to my queustion and I'm sharing it with you all.

Laravel Code:

```
$jsonEncoded = '{"accepted":{"first_order_number":{"consition":"between_date","value":"2021-11-28 00:00:00&2021-11-22 00:00:00"}},"removed":{}}';
    
$process = new Process(['ruby', 'convert_hashActiveSupport.rb'],null,null, $jsonEncoded);

$process->run();
    
// executes after the command finishes
if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
   throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
}
    
$data = $process->getOutput();
```

Ruby Code:

```
require 'yaml'
require 'json'
require "active_support/core_ext/hash/indifferent_access"

yaml_str = "#{ ARGF.read }"

parsed_output = JSON.parse(yaml_str)
yaml_output   = parsed_output.with_indifferent_access.to_yaml
puts yaml_output
```

Package required in laravel:

```
composer require symfony/process
```

Packages required in ruby:

```
gem install activesupport
gem install 'yaml'
```

And here I'm getting my expected output:

```
--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
accepted: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  first_order_date: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
    consition: between_date
    value: 2021-11-28 00:00:00&2021-11-22 00:00:00
removed: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess {}
```

Answer (score 2):

To convert hash to yaml in ruby we can use `yaml` library

```rb
require 'yaml'

data = {
    "accepted" => {
        "number_of_order" => {
            "condition" => "between_number", "value" => "0&5"
        }
    }, "removed" => {
        
    }
}

puts data.to_yaml
```

To convert associated array to yaml in php we can use `Symfony Yaml`

```php
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;

$jsonEncoded = '{"accepted":{"number_of_order":{"consition":"between_number","value":"0&5"}}}';

$array = json_decode($jsonEncoded, true);

print Yaml::dump($array);
```

To load php output yaml in ruby same `yaml` library can be used

```rb
require 'yaml'
yaml_str = ... # output generate from Symfony Yaml::dump
yaml_hash = YAML.load(yaml_str)
```

To load ruby output yaml in php we can use the same `Symfony Yaml`

```php
$yaml_str = ...; # output generate from ruby rhash.to_yaml
$yaml_associated_array = Yaml.parse(yaml_str);
```

Load ruby hash to php

```php
$data = "
--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
accepted: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  number_of_order: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
    condition: between_number
    value: 0&5
removed: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess {}
";

print $data;

$data = str_replace("---", "", preg_replace("/!ruby.*Access/", "", $data));
print $data;

$result = Yaml::parse($data);
var_dump($result);
```

Same can be achieved in ruby

```rb
data = %Q(
--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
accepted: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  number_of_order: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
    condition: between_number
    value: 0&5
removed: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess {}
)

result = str.gsub(/!ruby.*Access/, '').gsub("--- ", "")

puts result

puts YAML.load(result)
```

Note: We can also use other libraries

Comment: Hello, @Chandan Thank you for your answer but I have to put the whole code in a single file of PHP laravel. I'm using `Symfony Yaml` libraries for dumping an array and parsing an array.

Comment: @HitenGal the shared code is example of both ruby and php the main code is just 2 lines which strips unwanted lines from yaml.

Comment: so you are basically telling me if I just wrote

`use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;

$jsonEncoded = '{"accepted":{"number_of_order":{"consition":"between_number","value":"0&5"}}}';

$array = json_decode($jsonEncoded, true);

print Yaml::dump($array);`

this code so I will get my expected output right?

If you can able to share me code via GitHub or any other way so I can easily understand. Thank you

Comment: @HitenGal Yes it would produce `yaml format` which and can be read with the help of `yaml` module in ruby just like commented in the example.

Comment: But sir Can I do this without writing any ruby code? Because I don't want to create any ruby file or write any ruby code. I have to do all this process in PHP.

Comment: @HitenGal Yes you can use just php code I just include ruby for showing how you can use the php output in ruby.

Comment: @Chetan I just solve the issue. We Can't do this with alone PHP I need to write a ruby code for it. But you thank you for giving me this idea.